# How to build a tappable grid for Android app

Tags: android, android-layout

I am building a bowling scoring app, so the view my users will be interacting with most often needs to be a grid that they can fill in with scores round by round.

Reading up on options for building this grid, I'm pretty stuck on what the best solution could be:

- Grid Layout
- Grid View
- Recycler View
- Other?

All three come up in articles I read, and none seems to be standing out as better than the others for:

- Building a uniform grid (columns and rows same width and height, but
  a top row with double-wide columns)
- Making cells in that grid tappable
- Filling the cells with either a number or "colored in" corners after
  the user enters the result of their round

Could anyone explain what the relevant differences are, or if there's yet another approach I'm unaware of that could be useful for this purpose?  I'm a beginner at Android so still learning as I go.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few concepts before going ahead:

Any widget/ui component is a view. A layout is a ViewGroup which essentially means its a view that contains other views. Think of this as a container containing children views. A ViewGroup itself is a subclass of view meaning it has all the features of a view and some of its own.

Now coming back to your question:

Views with data in android normally follow a basic template.They take the data from the source and load it into the adapter(think of this as a bridge between raw data and what you see on the screen). So a listView is populated using a list adapter, but a listadapter can also be used to populate other types of views(such as GridView in this case).

A GridView is simply a row/column based view, meaning if you want to make something like a scorecard this would be a good choice.

A GridLayout is a layout which has its own set of rules about how views can be arranged inside it.(eg in a simple  linear layout, elements should be strictly arranged one below or one beside the other). In a GridLayout elements are arranged in rows/columns but note these are individual view elements inside the layout(think multiple elements grouped in a space), while gridview is kind of monolithic(as in you give it data and it will display it).

Now a recyclerview is a concept that is normally used when you have a reasonably large amount of data to display(usually only makes sense when you have data that normally overflows the screen). Earlier in android as you scrolled through your screen through a list the view in the list used to be rendered each time it appeared on screen. Overtime this was optimized so that we can recycle views that have already appeared on the screen instead of rendering them again from scratch.(think of this as a very high performance list view).

As for your application, i would say with the current information, a simple gridview should work super without going into recycler views etc.
A listview with two columns would also work if that is what you need.

This is a good tutorial on gridviews:
https://www.raywenderlich.com/127544/android-gridview-getting-started

and this too: 
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview

This is a good tutorial on list views:
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview

Comment: Thank you very much!  This is exactly the information I needed.  Much clearer now.